# python search the user name

Tags: python, python-re

```
Mon Apr 27 18:12:54 '<rdpDirect> ITC\109975@win_itsskdcbkp2_10.18.2.104
Mon Apr 27 18:14:31 '<rdpDirect> JDAWMSAPPDEV\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172
Mon Apr 27 18:14:32 '<rdpDirect> JDAWMSAPPDEV\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172
Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 '<rdpDirect> SAAMARTHA\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147
Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 '<rdpDirect> SAAMARTHA\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147
```

From the above text, need to search user name which is mentioned between the "\" and "@" sign. This can be numeric, characters, or alphanumeric. 

eg: in the above example, 109975, VINOTHKUMAR, UITSMUSR etc.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Could you please post the code you have written to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the group with zero or more characters within `\` and `@` character.

```
import re


data = "Mon Apr 27 18:12:54 ' ITC\\109975@win_itsskdcbkp2_10.18.2.104 Mon Apr 27 18:14:31 ' JDAWMSAPPDEV\\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172 Mon Apr 27 18:14:32 ' JDAWMSAPPDEV\\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172 Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 ' SAAMARTHA\\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147 Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 ' SAAMARTHA\\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147"
usernames = re.findall(r"\\(.*?)@", data)
print(usernames)
```

Output:

```
['109975', 'VINOTHKUMAR', 'VINOTHKUMAR', 'UITSMUSR', 'UITSMUSR']
```

`re.findall()` method returns list of non overlapping occurrences of the searched string. More can be read [in the official documentation of findall method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex should do the job. You can try `\\(.*?)\@`.
This "captures" text between `\` and `@`

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = '''
Mon Apr 27 18:12:54 ' ITC\\19975@win_itsskdcbkp2_10.18.2.104 Mon Apr 27 18:14:31 ' JDAWMSAPPDEV\\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172 Mon Apr 27 18:14:32 ' JDAWMSAPPDEV\\VINOTHKUMAR@win_jdawmsappdev_10.10.45.172 Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 ' SAAMARTHA\\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147 Mon Apr 27 18:24:21 ' SAAMARTHA\\UITSMUSR@win_saamarthaad_10.10.45.147'''
import re
print(re.findall('\\\([\d\w\W]+?)@', buffer))

['19975', 'VINOTHKUMAR', 'VINOTHKUMAR', 'UITSMUSR', 'UITSMUSR']
```

Comment: your regex does not cover all range of characters that can be in a name

Comment: eh, for 3am, wasn't the worst attempt :P